# No such file or directory - When running a service on JAR file

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm building a Spring Boot Application. I need to call outside files for using its service from my project.

Here is the root directory looks like,

[image]

I need to read files in the red box in my service and here is my example code,

```
@Value("${2c2p.payment-action-api.encrypt-key-file.path:cert/demo/demo2.crt}")
private String encryptKeyFilePath;
@Value("${2c2p.payment-action-api.decrypt-key-file.path:cert/demo/demo2.pfx}")
private String decryptKeyFilePath;
```

Where I call the **encryptKeyFilePath** or **decryptKeyFilePath** in my function on development (running via **mvn spring-boot:run**) everything works perfectly.

But when I build the JAR file, those files can't be seen.

Do I need to add some config on **application.properties** or put the **cert folder** to somewhere else ?

Code when I call the file,

```
private String encrypt(String message) throws CertificateException, IOException {
    String base64Str = pk.encryptMessage(message, pk.getPublicCert(encryptKeyFilePath));
    return base64Str;
}
```

Please help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Try using absolute paths

Comment: you need to put cert under resources

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ClassPathResource`, check the documentation :

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-classpath-file-access